# Navigation Controller between view controller and table view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard

Any ideas on how to add a Navigation Controller in iOS7 between a Table View and View Controller?

As soon as I embed the Navigation Controller to the table view the app crashes.

Without the Navigation Controller it works fine. But then the Table View becomes a View Controller. This is the code I'm using:

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"setup" sender:self];
```

Here is my storyboard: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/1ztdnb/8

Comment: Could be more clear about what you want to achieve? Why would you want a `UINavigationController` between those two controllers? And what do you mean by between?

Comment: I though it was the way to have the Table View work right? Because when I don't use the embed Nav Contoller the top bar disappears on the Table View and it looks like a normal view controller. You can see my storyboard here: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/1ztdnb/8

Comment: Aha, so what you are after is actually the `navigationBar` (top bar) to be displayed in your `TableViewController` but not `LoginViewController`, correct? Then you call     `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` for your `LoginViewController`. This way it would still be in the navigation stack, but will not display the navigation bar.

Comment: So. I should just remove the Navigation Controller in the middle? An add that code in the LoginViewController and push directly to the Table View? One more thing i forget to say is that LoginViewController comes from a Table View of it own.

Comment: You should embed your first view controller in the `NavigationController` and hide a navigation bar for it. Then yes, you can just use a `segue` or  "push" your `TableViewController`.

Comment: Thank you. But the the crash appears on the login in view controller. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, giving the comments here is what I think you want:

- A `LoginViewController` which is a subclass of a `UITableViewController`. Should not display navigationBar.
- A `ProfileViewController` also a subclass of a `UITableViewController`. Should display a `navigationBar`.
- When a user taps `LogIn` button, `ProfileViewController` should be "pushed".

So the whole trick is to make navigation bar hidden for one view controller and visible for another. Well this is very easy to achieve - just use  `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` in `viewWillAppear:` for each view controller

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES/NO animated:animated];
}
```